# How can I validate "Username" field in Laravel to contain letters, numbers, underscores and dashes?

Tags: laravel, validation, authentication

```
public function store()
{
$this->validate(request(),[
// Third try
‘username’ => ‘required|string|regex:/\w*$/|max:255|unique:users’,
// Second try
‘username’ => ‘required|string|regex:/^[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:[_-][A-Za-z0-9]+)*$/|max:255|unique:users‘,
// First try 
’username’ => ‘required|string|max:255’,
]);
}
```

The username field was working well with numbers included (at first try) but then I forgot to include “unique:users”, then the form started rejecting it (redirects back with username field underlined with wriggle red line). Plus I have used laravel’s “alpha_dash” several times but keeps rejecting the input. My aim is mixture of letters, numbers, underscores and dashes.

Some please help me make this right. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing parameters. It should be `unique:table,column,except,primarykeyname`

The last two parameters are optional. In your case, your validation for storing an user should look like this:

```php
'username' => 'required|string|regex:/\w*$/|max:255|unique:users,username',
```

That way, you're saying there should not be an user with that same username in the database.

When you want to update an user however, you should add the user's id as the third parameter so the validation for unique username ignores the user you're trying to update.

```php
'username' => 'required|string|regex:/\w*$/|max:255|unique:users,username,'.$user->id,
```

If your primary key is not named id, you add its name as the fourth parameter:

```php
'username' => 'required|string|regex:/\w*$/|max:255|unique:users,username,'.$user->userId.',userId',
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @IGP. I have implemented your approach, however I’m still getting the same result. I have also cleared the browser’s history and cookies. Still the same result. It’s strange because I wasn’t getting this at all. I have actually registered many users but had to migrate fresh to do some testing. I just don’t know what else to do now.

Answer (score 1):

When using the `regex` pattern, it may be necessary to specify rules in an array instead of using **pipe delimiters**, especially if the regular expression contains a **pipe** character :

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $validatedData = $request->validate([
        'username' => 
          array(
            'required',
            'unique:users,username',
            'max:255',
            'regex:/\w*$/'
          )
    ]);
}
```